# How to escape a sql query string with php to store it in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I am trying to store a sql query string in a MySQL field, and I am having problems correctly escaping the string.

If I insert the following string into the sql varchar field of the test table, using phpMyAdmin:

```
INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`='{$_POST['sql']}'
```

and then export it using phpMyAdmin, it gives me the following sql query:

```
INSERT INTO  `test`.`test` (`sql`)
VALUES ('INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`=''{$_POST[''sql'']}''');
```

If I want my own php script to do this, with what function do I escape:

```
INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`='{$_POST['sql']}'
```

to make it look like:

```
'INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`=''{$_POST[''sql'']}'''
```

I have a large number of sql queries I need to store for retrieval.

What is phpMyAdmin doing to the original string to create:

```
INSERT INTO  `test`.`test` (`sql`)
VALUES ('INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`=''{$_POST[''sql'']}''');
```

What is the function xyz where:

```
$a = "INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`='{$_POST['sql']}'";
$b = "INSERT INTO  `test`.`test` (`sql`)
VALUES ('INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`=''{$_POST[''sql'']}''')";
$b = xyz($a);
```

Comment: What functions/libraries are you using for working with MySQL?

Comment: Also do not forget to add `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sql'])` - this handle a lot of escaping itself aside from the fact of security and injection.

Comment: I am using mysqli or pdo

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sql']) . "'"; $encoded2 = base64_encode ($sql);  $decoded2 = base64_decode ($encoded2);  echo $decoded2; // $decoded2 does not = $sql, I don't understand

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: How is this about prepared statements or PDO or MySQLi?  What I am asking is if I want a database to store sql queries (PDO, MySQLi, old and deprecated or not), HOW do I prepare those queries so they are not executed or evaluated?

Answer (score 4):

You need [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sql']) . "'";
```

Comment: You beat me to it.. my answer was placed in comments.

Comment: I have a large number of queries that I need to store for retrieval - I would prefer not to edit every query, just process each query as an entire string.  And in any event, this does not return the original string (or am I missing something?)

Comment: @user1421347, the issue is that if you don't escape the data before creating a query, you can possibly get invalid query and in that case further escaping is useless. Of course you can parse the query inside `xyz()` and escape the extracted arguments, but as for me that is more complicated way.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, sorry, I can only give you +1 :)

Comment: It's not clear to me that you are understanding my question - stackoverflow.com is able to save the entire string (INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`='{$_POST['sql']}'), and reproduce here on this page - how do they do that?  Perhaps they are not using PHP/MySQL, but it has to be possible.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` will escape the single quotes for your query.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to read the code inside the database (e.g. access it via phpMyAdmin and copy&paste the code) but only use PHP to do that, you could encode it using a base64 system.

For encoding (storing in the database)

```
base64_encode($your_query);
```

For decoding (retrieving from the database)

```
base64_decode($your_result);
```

Assuming that you have all the queries in a single file that does not contain anything different, you could try this approach

```
$queryString = file_get_contents("queries.sql"); //reads the file and stores it as a single String
$queries = explode(';', $queryString);
foreach ($queries as $query)
  mysql_query( ... $query ... ); //Store each query in the database
```

Comment: 1970 something.. 1970 something - BIGGY.

Comment: Thanks - $str = "INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`='{$_POST['sql']}'"; $encoded = base64_encode ($str); $decoded = base64_decode ($encoded); echo $decoded; - why i
s this not the original string $str?

Comment: @user1421347: What have you used for sql? The $_POST['sql'] is evaluated and replaced. For me the solution seems to work, however I do not know what data you tried.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: Could you please provide a suitable solution if you decide on downvoting working solutions (even if the style is quite old)?

Comment: I don't want to evaluate  $_POST['sql'] - I want to store $str as a complete string and retrieve it as such

Comment: I want the output to be the actual string: INSERT INTO `test` SET `test`.`sql`='{$_POST['sql']}'

Comment: This is - as far as I know - not possible, because PHP handles the `{...}` as code that is executed/evaluated the moment that the string is created. Therefore, there never is any string in PHP that contains this information, which is why you can not store it inside the database. What would be possible, is to replace the `'{$_POST['sql']}'` part with a fixed (and reserved) constant, which is then replaced in code with the according value. However, this would require modifications to your code.

Comment: But surely it is possible, as phpMyAdmin is doing it?  I have restated the question at the end - there is some function xyz that accomplishes the transformation.  If it was not possible, then strings such as $_POST['abc'] would not be able to be stored in MySQL.

Comment: As far as I know, PHPMyAdmin is using the `mysql_real_escape_string()`. However, this IS a one-way function that is usually used to protect the database from SQL injection. It was NOT designed, to be undone - which is the reason why there is no function to do it. The only possibility for you would be to write you own escaping function for this scenario, or use some encoding/decoding (like stated above). However, there is still the problem that PHP will evaluate the `$_SOMETHING` when this is entered inside the source code. (PHPMyAdmin takes the string without evaluating it!)

Comment: I don't need it to be undone, although phpMyAdmin IS a two-way process.  They create $b from $a, which then can be executed to give the same result as $a.  How can you create string $b above from $a using mysql_real_escape_string()?  As I said above, stackoverflow.com is able to save the entire string (INSERT INTO test SET test.sql='{$_POST['sql']}'), and reproduce here on this page - how do they do that? Perhaps they are not using PHP/MySQL, but it has to be possible.

Comment: That is because the situation is entirely different. They get a string and store it. You LOAD a string via a PHP source file. Therefore, the PHP interpreter reads the string and interprets it. You can split the string above and piece it together, like this `"$" ."_POST" ...` and PHP would not interpret it. However, if you've got `$_POST` PHP tries to interpret it (due to its nature), which is why there is NO WAY to store that if it's part of the source code. A different approach would be to store all those queries in a file and read that via PHP (to store it linewise in the database).

Comment: You're very close to giving me the answer to my question.  That is what I want to do.  Get a string and store it.  How do you do that?

Comment: You can store those queries in a file (e.g. "queries.sql") and load that in PHP. This way PHP won't interpret the content but gives you the variable containing all the content instead. You can then parse this content in a loop, split each query after the semicolon (so you get only one query) and store that inside the database.